# Argparse. nargs + not working when custom type

Tags: python, argparse

Usually I had an argument like this:

```
parser.add_argument(
    "--distances",
    nargs="+",
    type=int,
    default=[1, 2, 3],
)
```

Now I need to include +- np.inf, and my idea was to get the list as strings, and map 'inf' to np.inf for instance, like this:

```
mapper = {'inf': np.inf, '-inf': -np.inf}

def process_bins(distances: List[str]) -> List[float]:
    return [mapper[distance] if mapper.get(distance) else float(distance)
            for distance in distances
            ]
parser.add_argument(
        "--distances",
        nargs="+",
        type=process_bins,
        default=[-np.inf, 2, np.inf],
    )
```

But when I do this, the list distances becomes the first element, and it fails.

For instance if I call the script with `--distances 1 2 3`, `args.distances = '1'`

What is happening?

Comment: ``type`` is the type of an element, not of all elements. The ``type`` is applied to *each* element, not to *all* elements. Consider how otherwise the first case would fail, since ``int([1, 2, 3])`` is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `type` is the converter for *each* element, not for *all* elements at once. It receives and should return only one element:

```py
mapper = {'inf': np.inf, '-inf': -np.inf}

def process_bin(distances: str) -> float:
    return mapper.get(distance, float(str))

parser.add_argument(
        "--distances",
        nargs="+",
        type=process_bins,
        default=[-np.inf, 2, np.inf],
    )
```

Note that `np.inf` is equal to `float('inf')` – using `type=float` works just as well here.

Comment: So many things to learn from this question. I did not know either that float had its own float. But I'm using it later for Pandas, I'm not sure if it will prefer numpy inf rather than float inf

Comment: numpy inf *is* float inf. Check ``np.inf == float('inf')`` and ``type(np.inf) is float``.